# I got this error type: 'List<Book>' is not a subtype of type 'RxList<Book>' of 'function result'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, flutter-getx

when i create Rxlist of model and i use it with obx in flutter

```
Obx(
                () {
                  return ListView(
                    controller: ScrollController(),
                    children: Book.books.where((e) => e.title.contains(query)).map((e) => CardBook(book: e,)).toList(),
                  );
                }
              ),
```

and the list is:

```
static RxList<Book> books=<Book>[].obs;


static add(String title,String author,String price,String imgPath,String desc,RxBool incart){
if (incart.value==null)
  incart.value=false;
books.add(Book(title,author,price,imgPath,desc));}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and add the stack trace as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try casting it as a list

```
() {
  List<Book> neeBooks = Book.books as List<Book>;//<--- add this
                  return ListView(
                    controller: ScrollController(),
                    children: newBooks.where((e) => e.title.contains(query)).map((e) => CardBook(book: e,)).toList(),
                  );
                }
              ),
```